# z3 C++ API: get operation of expr

Tags: c++, z3

I'm using z3 as a C++ library. 
Within in my current programming project I have boolean equations I'm simplifying using z3.

In order to use the simplified equations within my project I need the lhs, rhs and the operation of the simplified equation.

e.G.: expression (x==3)&&(x<5) is simplified to (x==3) in z3

```
(= x 3)
```

lhs argument -> x

```
expression.arg(0)
```

rhs argument -> 3

```
expression.arg(1)
```

How do I get the operation(=) ?

Any expr with more than 1 argument should have a operation right?

I'm looking at the API for 3hrs now and I just can't figure it out.

Hopefully, anyone can point me in the right direction!

Thanks
Toebs

Comment: what do you mean with "get the formula"? A (maths) equation always has a `==`.

Comment: I updated the question in order to clarify what I mean !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the "top" level operator as a string, i.e., for the original "and", and for the simplified "=" you can use:

```
expression.decl().name().str()
```

Comment: Good answer! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Function applications in Z3 are represented as a vector of arguments and a function declaration. For instance, suppose that function `f` is applied to the arguments `x` and `y`. In the C++ API this takes the shape of an `expr` object `e` which has `e.num_args()` arguments, `x`,`y` are `e.arg(0)`, `e.arg(1)` and `e.decl()` is applied to those arguments.

(Obviously this also works for 0 arguments, which is often referred to as `const` in various parts of the API, because they are applications of *constant functions*.)